# error while trying to run ruby file in terminal. How to fix it?

Tags: ruby

I wanna run my ruby file in the terminal but it was getting annoying typing ruby again and again so i did `chmod +x what.rb` in the files directory where what.rb is my file located in home/USER/shut/what.rb and tried typing what.rb in the terminal but it says command not found?
I tried getting the ruby interpreter's? location by typing which ruby and i got `/home/USER/.rbenv/shims/ruby` and added #!/usr/.rbenv/shims/ruby to the first line of what.rb and tried doing what.rb in the terminal again but it doesnt work.

Comment: Unless the file location is in `PATH`, you have to give path to it, so if you are in the same directory, it would be `./what.rb`.

Comment: So i need to replace the shebang line with ./what.rb?

Comment: No, you need to execute it with `./what.rb` provided you're in the same directory.

Comment: ^ Instead of running it as `what.rb`